# cmp not working - Intel x86 (IA32) Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, att

I'm trying to write a simple code in assembly and I'm having troubles when comparing two values using cmp. I want to jump to a certain point if my value is not between 65 and 90.

```
 cmp $65, (%ebx)
 jl looping
 cmp $90, (%ebx)
 jg check_minusculas
```

Running gdb I have that %ebx value is 0x80490f9 and using:

```
x /1db 0x80490f9
```

I get that (%ebx) is 77.
However, the program jumps to check_minusculas when obviously 77<90.
What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you forgot to use a size specifier and it defaults to long while you apparently want to use byte. Solution: use `cmpb`.

Comment: This worked, thanks! But what is happening "behind the scenes"? If it's a byte and defaults to long, doesn't it fill the other bytes as a 0?

Comment: No, it fetches the following 3 bytes as well from memory, whatever they may be.